# Lemma from PDE book

Tags: partial-differential-equations

This is Lemma 6.1 from Gilbarg - Trudinger.  It states "Let $\textbf{P}$ be a constant matrix which defines a nonsingular linear transformation $y=x\textbf{P}$ from $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.  Letting $u(x) \rightarrow \tilde{u}(y)$ under this transformation one verifies easily that $A^{ij}D_{ij}u(x) = \tilde{A}^{ij}D_{ij}\tilde{u}(y)$, where $\tilde{\textbf{A}} = \textbf{P}^t\textbf{A}\textbf{P}$."

Here, we are using the summation convention, and $A^{ij}$ is a constant matrix with $A^{ij} = A^{ji}$.

I have no idea where this is coming from.  It says it's an easy verification... but even trying to do this with 2 by 2 matrices gives a huge mess.  Second, what exactly does $u(x) \rightarrow \tilde{u}(y)$ mean?  Is $\tilde{u}$ the same function but just a different variable?  Why not call it $u(y)$ then?  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to perform a "rotation and stretching" $(P)$ of coordinates which transforms $u$ (defined on $\Omega$) into a function $\tilde{u}$ defined on $P(\Omega)$ so that $\tilde{u}$ satisfies a nice equation.

Computationally, we have $u(x) = \tilde{u}(Px)$. The general formula (by the Chain Rule) for $D^2u$ is 
$$D^2u(x) = P^T D^2\tilde{u}(Px) P.$$

Thus, we have
$$0 = tr(AD^2u(x)) = tr(AP^T D^2\tilde{u}(Px) P) = tr(PAP^T D^2\tilde{u}(Px)).$$

For a simple example try $u_{xx} + u_{xy} + u_{yy} = 0$, say defined on $B_1$. By rotating coordinates to the $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$ directions we can write the equation without mixed derivatives, and by stretching in one direction and squeezing in the other we obtain harmonic $\tilde{u}$ defined on some rotated ellipse.

The idea of changing coordinates is also very useful in scaling arguments for PDE, where we have some estimate in $B_1$ which we would like to apply at all scales.

Comment: Two things: Do you mean xP instead of Px?  Also, if the traces are equal, I don't get how we can conclude that the sums are equal.  The notation $A^{ij}D_{ij}u(x)$  means that we sum up all the entries.  So, could you please explain how this simplifies into just the trace part mattering?

Comment: First, observe that $xP = P^Tx$. So just interchange $P$ and $P^T$ in the above argument to get the desired conclusion. (Note that my final answer has $P$ and $P^T$ swapped compared to what you want). For your second question, check that for arbitrary $n x n$ matrices $M,N$ we have $tr(MN) = M_{ij}N_{ij}$, sum implicit.

Comment: Why is $0 = tr(AD^2u(x))$?

Answer (score 1):

The definition is
$$
\tilde{u}(xP)=u(x),
\qquad\textrm{or equivalently,}\qquad
\tilde{u}(y)=u(xP^{-1}).
$$
Then use the [beloved rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule).